# Finding a function that is locally invertible but not globally invertible

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Find a function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $f(0,0,0) = (1,2,3)$ that is locally invertible around $(0,0,0)$ but  not globally invertible on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I am struggling to find one that is not injective. I am also wondering if there is a way to show that $f$ is locally invertible without computing the determinant of $3×3$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f(0) = 0$ is easy to construct. Now take $$(x,y,z) \mapsto (f(x)+1,y+2,z+3)$$

Comment: your function satisfies $f(0,0,0) =(1,2,3)$, but does it satisfy $f$ is not injective?

Comment: @SihyunKim Take, for instance, $(x, y, z)\mapsto (\sin(x)+1, y+2, z+3)$.

Comment: @GitGud  Oh, I got it . Thanks.

Comment: @SihyunKim No problem. It's odd, though, that you didn't up vote this answer.